# Google App Engine doesn't recognize CNAME record

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

Four days ago, I registered a domain name (call it xyz.com) and verified my ownership in Google's App Engine. I added a CNAME record for host 'www.xyz.com' and set the answer to 'ghs.googlehosted.com'.

But when I go into the App Engine's developer's console to associate the domain with a project (Compute > App Engine > Settings > Custom Domains), I can select 'www.xyz.com' but I can't press Add. That is, it recognizes the domain but the Add button is disabled.

At first, I thought it just needed more time. But when I visit www.xyz.com in a browser, Google says "The requested URL / wasn't found on this server." So the CNAME record has had some effect.

It occurs to me that I may need to go through Google Apps to associate my domain with the the project. Is this the case? Has someone succeeded in associating a custom domain with a project without going through Google Apps?

Comment: the custom domain works, no longer need google apps

Comment: I think i had this issue once. After entering the domain i had to click in some other form control to make the add button active. You could also set the Add button to enabled in the DOM tree and see what happens.